# What can I substitute for radish when making kimchi?

Tags: substitutions, kimchi, radish

I want to try the recipe but could not get radish.

Comment: Kimchi doesn't necessarily require radish.  Why not just leave it out?

Comment: Yes.... what are you looking for in a substitute?  Do you eat the radish, normally? The radish greatly enhances and accelerates the "souring" of the kimchee. In that regard, I don't think there's anything that really works as a substitute.  However, you can make a perfectly fine kimchee without it, it's just a little bit different.

Answer (score 1):

Jicama. It has the same kind of crunch and taste is also subtle.

Comment: A substitute used in kimchi must also be safe to ferment in that process. Is your recommended substitute?

Comment: There is pickled jicama, so should be fine as kimchi.